# Verb + Suffix ‘Ion’ as noun

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns, suffixes, linguistics

I've been wondering on the usage of the suffix ***-ion*** and what it means if put at the end of a verb.

I notice that oftentimes it means the process/ action of the verb.

**Examples:** Transformation, investigation, deforestation.

What makes me question are verbs like *create*. I reasoned that the noun *creation* would mean *the process of creating*, but it also means *the end product of creating*.

Verbs like *incline* or *dispose* also confuses me, because *to incline* means *to make (someone) tend/prone to something, but the noun *inclination* means *tendencies* as opposed to the process of the action.

My question is:

Can **verbs + ion** be defined as other things rather than the process or the action of the verb itself?

Comment: To incline does not just mean to make someone tend; people can incline for themselves. I incline to the view that [a certain politician] s a 'bozo'.

Comment: An example is 'satisfaction' which isn't the act of the verb 'satisfy' but its *result*. The first and third of your examples are also like the 'creation' example: 'transformation'  and 'deforestation' being the end result.

Comment: The suffix _-ion_ is rare (GEdgar gives a couple of examples). The suffix _-ation_  is very common, and often, though not always, has a matching verb in _-ate_.

Answer (score 2):

There is this explanation

> **-ion**  SUFFIX
> 1 Forming nouns denoting verbal action.
> ‘communion’
> 1.1 Denoting a resulting state or product.
> ‘oblivion’
> **usage** The suffix -ion is usually found preceded by s (-sion), t (-tion), or x (-xion)
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-ion)

Comment: -ion can also be preceded by c (e.g. suspicion).

Comment: It says "usually" and the main examples are two cases not preceded by any of those.

Answer (score 0):

> Can verbs + ion be defined as other things rather than the process or the action of the verb itself?

Your question is strange as you have already shown that it can be with your example "creation".

*"Creation (uncountable) occurred on the 23rd of September 4004BC at approximately 18:45 hours"*

*"The dragon, the behemoth, and the cockatrice are but a few of God's creations (countable)"*

*"Explanation (uncountable) is required!" he said angrily.* - The act of explaining.

*"I have an explanation(countable)" I replied.* - That which is explained; an instance or example of explanation.